# smarty modify в phpsrorm Как адаптировать?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

```
{|foreach from=$arrOfices item=diller key=key|}

{|/foreach|}
```

Как сделать чтобы phpstorm понимал такой синтаксис smarty? - все тоже самое только есть вертикальные палочки.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Нажмите `Ctrl+Alt+S`, выберите вкладку Plugins. Включите соответствующий плагин. Хотя поддержка **Smarty** в PhpStorm стоит по дефолту. Возможно вы используете `*.php` файл. PhpStorm понимает синтаксис **Smarty** в `*.tpl` файлах

Comment: У нас Smarty используется модифицирован, синтаксис в вопросе. Настроить через настройки неполучилось. Спасибо.